# How to hide a layout behind another component within xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to hide a layout behind another component in my `activity_main.xml`. I am using a bottom sheet and would only like to view the top portion. The bottom should be hidden behind my toolbar. Is there a function or property that will push the layout behind the component?

`main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_app_bar"
        android:name="com.ds.base.fragments.TopAppBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_bottom_app_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_app_bar"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_app_bar"
        android:name="com.ds.base.fragments.BottomAppBarFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">

    </fragment>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/time_remaining_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/time_remaining_bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/main_bottom_app_bar"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Making it invisible instead of putting it behind something else may be more efficient.

Comment: You can add a `BottomSheetCallback` to your `BottomSheet` and then set the alpha for your view that needs to be hidden based on the position of your `BottomSheet`, something else you could do is change the view position in stead of setting the alpha.

Comment: use stubviews for different layout

Answer (score 0):

use in xml

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

or

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

also use in java(activity) code

```
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I dont need to hide the whole view. Just the bottom part

Answer (score 0):

To bring any `View` to top, You have to call
`yourView.bringToFront()`